# Import/export cannot work in browser by using babel.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I add babel compiler in my page to use ES6 syntax by below:

```
<script src="babel.min.js"></script>
```

And create a simple module in M.js as below:

```
export var M={
    p:3
};
```

And use it in my page:

```
<script type="text/babel">
    import {M} from './M';
    console.log(M.p);
</script>
```

But meet below error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

How can I make module works in browser? Does babel.js support module or not? If not, if there's other way I can make ES6 module syntax works in browser.

Comment: You have to use a module loader along with Babel.

Comment: @gcampbell What kind of module loader should I use? Do you mean I need to add "<script src="require.js"></script>" in my page, right?

Comment: Generally you'd compile your code in Node with something like Browserify, then load that in a script tag, rather than compiling in your browser itself with `text/babel`.

Comment: instead try `import {M} from './M.mjs'` and rename your M file with extension `.mjs`. This fixed the problem. Also your first script that gets loaded by the html should look something like `<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" src="index.js"></script>`

Comment: @GotToFigure still says 'require is not defined'

Answer (score -2):

Use a dynamic ES Module loader like [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) and the [Babel Plugin](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-babel)

Comment: I can't see instructions for using this in a browser

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried setting the data-plugin attribute to "transform-es2015-modules-umd"? As below?

```
<script data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" type="text/babel">
    import M from './M';
    console.log(M.p);
</script>
```

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Invalid plugin specified in Babel options: "transform-es2015-modules-umd"`